# How to detect XMLHttpRequest errors in a Chrome App

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-app

How do I detect `XMLHttpRequest` errors in Chrome App.

For example I want to know when `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` is being generated so I can output an error message to the user.

`XMLHttpRequest.onerror` is triggered however I cannot distinguish between this error or `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`

Comment: Did you try displaying the argument to the error handler with console.log?

Comment: Yes I tried but there was nothing relevant

Comment: Some errors come through the success callback, because the request received a response, but it contained an error code (e.g., 412 instead of 200). I assume you dumped out the response objects as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you want more control, you could use the chrome.sockets permission and determine the connection problem "manually". I do something like this in [chromesocketxhr.js](https://github.com/kzahel/web-server-chrome/blob/master/chromesocketxhr.js)